# prevent UINavigationBar from growing on UITableView scroll iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I'm having an issue where I have the following views:

```
|||||||||||||
|           |
|    Nav    |
|-----------|
|  SomeView |
|-----------|
|           |
|   Table   |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|||||||||||||
```

Upon scrolling the tableview down.

```
|||||||||||||
|           |
|           |
|    Nav    |
|           |
|-----------|
|           |
|   Table   |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|||||||||||||
```

This only occurs when prefersLargeTitles is set to true. Inspecting this with the Xcode debugger, I see that the navigation bar frame grows as the content offset of the tableview gets bigger (Im panning the UITableView downward). Any idea how to prevent the navigation bar from growing (and hence covering my someView thats pinned above the uitableview?).

Update:I was able to reproduce with a very simple project. Here is the source code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    let testView = TestView()
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(testView)
    testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Here is what i see:

[image]

[image]

Comment: SomeView should _not_ be "pinned above the table view". It should be pinned to the top of the safe area, exactly so that it moves when the navigation bar changes height.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is pinned to the view controller's safe are top anchor.

Comment: Does this only happen while the table is being dragged and then it snaps back or does it stay this way when you release it?

Comment: It is because you make: navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true, make it FALSE
 and try

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the changing height of the navigation bar but the layout of your views. Things in a view controller's main view should be pinned by autolayout constraints ultimately to the top of the safe area, exactly so that as the navigation bar changes height, they remain exposed to view. That is what the safe area *is*.

**EDIT** You've now updated your question to include some code. This is the entirety of your constraint code:

```
testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

That code is faulty. `testView` has no `height` constraint, so your layout is ambiguous. So it sounds like that's the cause of the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I did pin the topmost view to the view controller's view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor. This issue happens when thats the case.

Comment: Then there's something else going on. I can't reproduce the issue based on what you've said. If you're using a UITableViewController with something else in its view other than the table view, that might be the problem.

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController with the the someView pinned to the top safe area, and the tableview pinned to the bottom of someView. Both are subviews of the view controller's view.

Comment: That's great. That's the layout I configured for my test of this situation, and I'm not seeing the problem. In fact, the navigation bar doesn't shrink when I scroll.

Comment: i updated my post with some screenshots to give you an idea of whats going on. Thanks for looking!

Comment: if there was no height, you wouldnt see a blue view. The testView has an intrinsic content size that gives it the height you see here.

Comment: I can go only on what you tell me. You continue to fail to supply sufficient information to allow the problem to be reproduced.

Comment: It can be inferred that if you can see the view, its because it has a valid height. Otherwise, you wouldn't even see the blue. Nonetheless, i dont think that the height of this testView is the cause of the navigationBar overlapping the view as you pull the tableview down.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are not about "inferring" things. It is your job to provide an MCVE; it is not my job to "infer". I am happy to consider the matter if you will kindly provide an MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve